# Polymer.js browser compatibility - Can't see CSS in Firefox and Safari

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, compatibility, polymer-1.0

Hi I'm new in using Polymer.js and I'm building my HTML custom tags in order to reuse them in my front-end work. The problem is that when I try to open my index.html in Safari and Firefox I see the only HTML without all the CSS. In Chrome everything works perfectly. I can't understand why it happens. 
I use Polymer 1.0.0 and Firefox and Safari are in their latest versions. 
Any suggestions? 
Thank you all in advance.

Here is the code (As you notice I've included the webcomponents-lite.min.js):

index.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <title>Polymer Project</title>
    <script src="../../bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="app/components/pd-dashboard/dashboard-articles.html" />

<div class="row">

    <dashboard-articles> </dashboard-articles>

        </div>
     <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
</div>

</html>
```

dashboard-articles.html:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="import" href="../../components/articles/article-2col/article-2col.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../components/articles/article-1col/article-1col.html">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="css/text" href="../../components/pd-dashboard/dashboard-articles.css" />
<!-- Fonts --> 
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:800,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="../../bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>


<dom-module id="dashboard-articles">
<template>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" style="margin: 5px">    

</div>

  <div class="row"> 
      <hr>         
    <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-5">
              <article-1col></article-1col>
              </div>
           <div class="col-sm-7">


           </div>   

       </div> 

   </div>    


</template>
 </dom-module>


     <script>
            Polymer({
                is: "dashboard-articles"
            });

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! 
The `<link>` to the .css file must be inside the tag `<template>` in each component you create!